# openni_kinect install errors

Tags: openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there when i try to install openni_kinect for diamond back i get this error:

```
aether@aether:/opt/ros/diamondback/ros$ sudo aptitude install ros-diamondback-openni-kinect
[sudo] password for aether: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reading extended state information       
Initialising package states... Done
Writing extended state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ros-diamondback-openni-kinect 
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  nite-dev openni-dev ps-engine 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 43 not upgraded.
Need to get 5,608kB of archives. After unpacking 19.5MB will be used.
Writing extended state information... Done
Get:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ lucid/main ros-diamondback-openni-kinect 0.2.1-s1306611764~lucid [5,608kB]
Fetched 5,608kB in 6s (906kB/s)                                                 
Selecting previously deselected package ros-diamondback-openni-kinect.
(Reading database ... 184411 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking ros-diamondback-openni-kinect (from .../ros-diamondback-openni-kinect_0.2.1-s1306611764~lucid_i386.deb) ...
Setting up openni-dev (0.1.0~lucid) ...
Illegal instruction
Illegal instruction
Illegal instruction
dpkg: error processing openni-dev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 132
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nite-dev:
 nite-dev depends on openni-dev (= 0.1.0~lucid); however:
  Package openni-dev is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing nite-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ps-engine:
 ps-engine depends on openni-dev (= 0.1.0~lucid); however:
  Package openni-dev is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing ps-engine (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                            No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                        dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ros-diamondback-openni-kinect:
 ros-diamondback-openni-kinect depends on ps-engine; however:
  Package ps-engine is not configured yet.
 ros-diamondback-openni-kinect depends on nite-dev; however:
  Package nite-dev is not configured yet.
 ros-diamondback-openni-kinect depends on openni-dev; however:
  Package openni-dev is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing ros-diamondback-openni-kinect (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 openni-dev
 nite-dev
 ps-engine
 ros-diamondback-openni-kinect
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up openni-dev (0.1.0~lucid) ...
Illegal instruction
Illegal instruction
Illegal instruction
dpkg: error processing openni-dev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 132
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ros-diamondback-openni-kinect:
 ros-diamondback-openni-kinect depends on openni-dev; however:
  Package openni-dev is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing ros-diamondback-openni-kinect (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ps-engine:
 ps-engine depends on openni-dev (= 0.1.0~lucid); however:
  Package openni-dev is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing ps-engine (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nite-dev:
 nite-dev depends on openni-dev (= 0.1.0~lucid); however:
  Package openni-dev is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing nite-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openni-dev
 ros-diamondback-openni-kinect
 ps-engine
 nite-dev
```

I have been trying to solve for days to no avail.

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04, on a RoBoard-110 with special kernal, 2.6.34.9

Thank you in advanced
Chris Paton

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10123/openni_kinect-install-errors/) by [Aether Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/627/aether-robotics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-05-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is your problem:

`Setting up openni-dev (0.1.0~lucid) ... Illegal instruction Illegal instruction Illegal instruction`

I'm not familiar with the hardware you are using. Is it i386 compatible?
Illegal instruction sounds like an instruction that is not executable on the system.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-06-01**:
See some of the other questions around (especially ones for ARM since they also have to remove things like SSE flags). e.g. http://answers.ros.org/question/130/openni-compilation-error-diamondback-version .

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-05-31**:
You would need to look in the CMakeLists.txt of each package. Hopefully when you compile from source you will automatically stumble upon that (although you can crosscompile with g++).

**Comment by [Aether Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/627/aether-robotics/) on 2011-05-31**:
ok, will remove and try from source, how would i remove SSE flags? post on robosavvy forum (who sell roboard to europe and all UK where i am) telling you how to do it for openCV in windows.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-05-31**:
You installed both ROS and openni_kinect from source? Also, you may have to remove hardcoded SSE flags in things like openni_kinect, but I would think that rosrun should work just fine if you install Diamondback from source.

**Comment by [Aether Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/627/aether-robotics/) on 2011-05-31**:
tried installing from source same error with illegal instruction, get with rosrun too. looked into sse on roboard, it isnt supported

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-05-31**:
Can you try installing from source? I don't know if the Roboard supports things like SSE/2/3, but many of the debs are built with SSE support enabled.

**Comment by [Aether Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/627/aether-robotics/) on 2011-05-31**:
yeah it is i386 compatable. i get illegal instruction msg when try to run rviz too: http://www.roboard.com/RB-110.htm